# Easiest way to create a custom keystroke hotkey on a Mac?

Tags: mac, hotkeys

I feel like I'm in a bit over my head here. All I want is to change it so that when I press a key on my mac (CapsLock) or perhaps F12, instead of doing what it was originally mapped to do, it inputs a keystroke (Ctrl + Option + S). This would make work a lot easier. Why is this so hard to figure out how to do?

I installed one of the many suggested apps I found during my research, Karabiner, and I thought mapping a keystroke like this would be as simple as selecting the key, and choosing which keys I want it to input instead. Turns out, in order to create a complex modifier, I need to know how to edit JSON files which is totally out of my scope. Even the web based generator is largely impossible to understand for a layman, and there's little to no documentation on how to actually use it: https://genesy.github.io/karabiner-complex-rules-generator/

Appreciate any tips on this.

Comment: Hello, you shouldn't ask about easiest way, as that makes your question opinion-based and it'll be closed.

Answer (score 0):

First, you may be able to accomplish all the key mapping you need via the stock system preferences on MacOS. Unlike, Windows, the Mac is very flexible when it comes to managing keyboard shortcuts.

## Native Solution

(I believe what you want is the last part of this)

- On your Mac, choose **Apple menu**  > **System Settings**, click **Keyboard**  in the sidebar (you may need to scroll down), then click Keyboard Shortcuts on the right.
- Select **App Shortcuts** on the left, click the **Add** button , click the **Application** pop-up menu, then choose a specific app or **All Applications**.
  For example, to set a shortcut for a TextEdit command, choose TextEdit. If an app isn’t in the list, choose Other, then locate the app using the Open dialog. Some apps may not allow you to set keyboard shortcuts.
  If you want to set a shortcut for a menu command that appears in many apps, choose 'All Applications'.
- In the Menu Title field, type the menu command for which you want to create a shortcut, exactly as the command appears in the app, including the > character (type ->), ellipses (type three periods without spaces or press Option-; (semi-colon)), or other punctuation.
- Click in the Keyboard Shortcut field, press the key combination that you want to use as the keyboard shortcut, then click Done.For example, press the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> at the same time. You can use a key only once in a key combination.

## Software Solutions

## [BetterTouchTool](https://setapp.com/apps/bettertouchtool)

> The app lets you create expanded AutoHotkey shortcuts on Mac for a
> faster workflow. This is even better than AHK for Mac because you can
> use every input method you like, not just the keyboard.

## [Almighty](https://setapp.com/apps/almighty)

> While Almighty may not take a direct approach to scripting macros, it
> does allow for a deep level of customization to improve your workflow.
> You can manage your Mac's Dock to only show active apps, and control
> system settings like **keyboard input**, screen savers, dark mode, and
> scheduled shutdowns with more granularity.

[Source 1](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/mac-help/mchlp2271/mac)
[Source 2](https://setapp.com/how-to/autohotkey-for-mac)