# change default apple keyboard shortcut of input sources

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, input-languages

I'd like to be able to change the default keystrokes to change input sources. I use Dvorak, but there are some apps like Blender, where it's easier to use the standard keyboard layout.

Apple offers Ctrl-Spacebar, which I use, but it's not optimal. I'd rather change it to something like Ctrl-~ (control-tilde) because it's a better location for quickly changing with my non-mouse hand.

But I can't find the place to do this... is it doable? And how is it done?

Comment: I just answered a similar question today.  - Does this help? https://superuser.com/a/1793010/598567

Comment: Input Sources has its own key command setting in Prefs/Settings

Comment: @KalamalkaKid all good until we get to the menu title of the shortcut, since to my knowledge changing input sources doesn't appear in any menu. What then?

Comment: @Tetsujin : found it, that worked. Thanks